# ASP.NET Add Picture to TableCell

Tags: c#, asp.net, tablecell

I'm kind of new to ASP.NET and I would like to know how it's possible to add a Picture on a TableCell. What I am doing is the following :

I have two pictures that Represent Male &  Female. I want to load a picture of a male if "sex" = 1 , if it's "2", display the female picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to just add IMG tag.

```
cell5.Text = string.Format("<img src='{0}' />", blaa == "1"? "Male.png" : "Female.png");
```

`string.Format` will substitute {0} with the second parameter - which will select either male or female based on value of "blaa".

If you use the code as is - you should place the images into the same directory as your ASPX file.

Comment: What should I really edit on this code ? {0} represent what ? and should I put Male.png & Female.png path ? .
THERE IS error in ","  between make & female